# How to sign cert with an arbitrary or deprecated extension

Tags: go, ssl, x509certificate, x509

For example say I want to sign a cert with an arbitrary or deprecated extension (nsCertType for example): https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man5/x509v3_config.html

I believe I'm supposed to add the arbitrary extension as part of the certificate as per below but how / where do you discover the asn1 object identifier? I've read more documentation that I care to admit today and am still stumped.

```
tmpl := &x509.Certificate{
    SerialNumber:          big.NewInt(time.Now().Unix()*1000),
    Subject:               pkix.Name{CommonName: "edgeproxy", Organization: []string{"edgeproxy"}},
    NotBefore:             now,
    NotAfter:              now.Add(caMaxAge),
    ExtraExtensions:       []pkix.Extension{
        {
            Id: asn1.ObjectIdentifier{}, //what goes here
            Critical: false,
            []byte("sslCA"),
        },
    },
    ExtKeyUsage:           []x509.ExtKeyUsage{x509.ExtKeyUsageServerAuth,x509.ExtKeyUsageClientAuth,x509.ExtKeyUsageEmailProtection, x509.ExtKeyUsageTimeStamping, x509.ExtKeyUsageMicrosoftCommercialCodeSigning, x509.ExtKeyUsageMicrosoftServerGatedCrypto, x509.ExtKeyUsageNetscapeServerGatedCrypto} ,
    KeyUsage:              x509.KeyUsageCRLSign | x509.KeyUsageCertSign,
    IsCA:                  true,
    BasicConstraintsValid: true,
}
```

In python I would do this but don't know how to port this into go (which is what I'm doing at the end of the day):

```
    OpenSSL.crypto.X509Extension(
        b"nsCertType",
        False,
        b"sslCA"
    ),
```

Comment: Thanks! Already found what I needed! Want to make that an answer and I will accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go sources at https://golang.org/src/encoding/asn1/asn1.go define:

```
// An ObjectIdentifier represents an ASN.1 OBJECT IDENTIFIER.

type ObjectIdentifier []int
```

So the object identifier (OID for short) is an array of integers. The asn1 module has methods to parse them, like `parseObjectIdentifier`.

This is the structure you need to put after the `Id:` attribute.

But now you need to find out the OID you want.

While difficult to read, OpenSSL source code can show you OIDs of many things in the X.400/X.500/X.509 worlds, or at least those known by OpenSSL.

If you go to https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/1aec7716c1c5fccf605a46252a46ea468e684454/crypto/objects/obj_dat.h

and searching on `nsCertType` you get:

```
{"nsCertType", "Netscape Cert Type", NID_netscape_cert_type, 9, &so[407]},
```

`so` is defined previously, and if you jump at its 407<sup>th</sup> item you see:

```
    0x60,0x86,0x48,0x01,0x86,0xF8,0x42,0x01,0x01,  /* [  407] OBJ_netscape_cert_type */
```

and doing a final search on `OBJ_netscape_cert_type` in same file gives:

```
  71,    /* OBJ_netscape_cert_type           2 16 840 1 113730 1 1 */
```

which means the corresponding OID is 2.16.840.1.113730.1.1

Or you can decode the above list of integers that describe this OID (see [How does ASN.1 encode an object identifier?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5929050/how-does-asn-1-encode-an-object-identifier) for details).

- first `0x60` is `96`<sub>10</sub> so `2*40 + 16`, which means the OID starts with `2.16.`
- then each other one is in "base128" form: if most significant bit is 1 combine the 7 least significant bits together of all following numbers until one has 0 as most significant bit
- `0x86` is `10000110`<sub>2</sub> so has to go with `0x48` aka `01001000`<sub>2</sub> so it is in fact `00001101001000`<sub>2</sub> or `840`<sub>10</sub>
- `0x01` is less than 128 so it is itself, `1`
- `0x86` is still `10000110`<sub>2</sub> but has to be paired with both `0xF8` (`11111000`<sub>2</sub>) and `0x42` (`01000010`<sub>2</sub> and we stop here since first bit is 0) so `000011011110001000010`<sub>2</sub> altogether or `113730`<sub>10</sub>
- and the two last `0x01` are themselves, `1`.

so we do get again `2.16.840.1.113730.1.1`

You can double check it at some online OID browser like here:
http://oid-info.com/cgi-bin/display?oid=2.16.840.1.113730.1.1&action=display
that gives the following description for it:

> Netscape certificate type (a Rec. ITU-T X.509 v3 certificate extension
>   used to identify whether the certificate subject is a Secure Sockets
>   Layer (SSL) client, an SSL server or a Certificate Authority (CA))

You can then even browse various arcs, like the netscape one, or others, to find out other OIDs.

You also get the full ASN.1 notation:

```
{joint-iso-itu-t(2) country(16) us(840) organization(1) netscape(113730) cert-ext(1) cert-type(1)}
```